# How to solve T(n) = T(n-1) + n^2 with recursion tree

Tags: algorithm, recursion, recurrence

I'm having trouble solving this T(n)=T(n-1)+n^2 with a recursion tree, can anyone help me with a pic so I can understand easily?
thx.

Comment: There has to be an exit condition with recursion, this thing could go on forever.

Comment: You need a base case. What is T(0)?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a computer programming question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just expand the equation:

[image]

Using the mathematical induction, you can write if
[image]

[image]